# How to check if each word of a column is present in multiple columns of the same DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I want to check for each row of the Words column, is that word present in any column.

For example, for the word, "ANAND", it will check the whole columns of Area, City, City2 and States and then the row for a new column would be updated as 'Place'. If it's not present, then it'll be None.

You can see the example given below. I have tried multiple approaches but the function's taking 30+ minutes to process and then at the end, I am getting zero matches when that's not true. Can anybody please help?

```
Input:
    Words        Area           City       City2        States
0   ANAND        Whitefield     Abohar     Achalpur     Maharashtra
1   Gujarat     Koramangala     Adilabad   Achhnera     Uttar Pradesh
2   PARDESHI  Electronic City   Agartala   Adalaj       Gujarat
3   PARDESHI    Anand Chowk     Agra       Adilabad     Telangana

Output:
    Words        Area           City       City2        States          Result       
0   ANAND        Whitefield     Abohar     Achalpur     Maharashtra     None       
1   Gujarat     Koramangala     Adilabad   Achhnera     Uttar Pradesh   Place       
2   PARDESHI  Electronic City   Agartala   Adalaj       Gujarat         None       
3   PARDESHI    Anand Chowk     Agra       Adilabad     Telangana       None
```

Edit: - Data added, picture removed.

Comment: Kindly share code or data not pics

Comment: Sure my bad. Added the tabular input and output samples